# vuejs v-for increment value not working well

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My aim is to keep the main question as a, b, c ...
but for sub question must keep increasing like 1, 2, 3, 4 ....... even when new main question is created.

Then i add v-text inside the v-for, but it not working well. please refer the picture/code below for more clarification.

Vue Code

```
el: '#question',
data() {
    return {
        questions: [],
        count: 1
    }
},
methods: {
    incrementItem() {
        this.count = this.count + 1
        return this.count + '. Sub Question'
    }
......................
```

Blade Code

```
<li v-for="(subQuestion, position) in question.children">
    <div class="panel panel-default m-t-15 p-t-15 p-b-15 p-r-15 p-l-15">
        <div>
            <h5 class="bold pull-left" v-text="incrementItem()"></h5>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" v-on:click="removeSubQuestion(index, position)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" v-model="subQuestion.text">Insert Question</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image: Blade View]

The number for the sub question also change when typing into question text box.

If you need more clarification, please comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed prop to numerate childrens before you render them. Like this:

```js
computed: {
    numeratedSubQuestions() {
        let iterator = 1;
        return this.questions.map(question => {
            question.children = question.children.map(child => {
                child.num = iterator;
                iterator++;

                return child;
            });

            return question;
        });
    }
}
```

Because of computed prop it will recalculate nums and show only actual numbers. Also you need to use `numeratedSubQuestions` instead of `questions`
Template for subquestion:

```html
<li v-for="(subQuestion, position) in question.children">
    <div class="panel panel-default m-t-15 p-t-15 p-b-15 p-r-15 p-l-15">
        <div>
            <h5 class="bold pull-left" v-text="subQuestion.num"></h5>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right" v-on:click="removeSubQuestion(index, position)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" v-model="subQuestion.text">Insert Question</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

You can read more about computed props [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)